# Yii2 execute controller and show view from package in vendor

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my case I am trying to execute `slide(controller)/index(action)` and render the corresponding view ( `index` ). They are both in my vendor folder like this way:

```
vendor/
   tomaivanovtomov/
      yii2-revolution/
         controllers/
         models/
         views/
            slide/
               index.php
```

How should I construct my url to reach them ? Before this it was simply `www.example.com\backend\web\slide\index`. Now it gave me an expected error but I realized that I don't know how to reach them. Is there any way or I should override the controller at least in my `backend\controllers\` directory and the call it ? Thank you in advance! 
**EDIT** Now I did it this way:

```
 1. Override the `SlideController.php` to my `backend\controllers\` directroy
 2. Extend the `vendor/tomaivanovtomov/revolution/controllers/SlideController.php`
 3. In action index set the layout to `$this->layout = '@vendor/tomaivanovtomov/yii2-revolution/views/slide/index';`
 4. And the return to `return $this->render('@vendor/tomaivanovtomov/yii2-revolution/views/slide/index', [
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'hidden' => $hidden
                ]);`
```

This is my `slide/index` action:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->layout = '@vendor/tomaivanovtomov/yii2-revolution/views/slide/index';

        $searchModel = new SlideSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        $hidden = new Slide();

        return $this->render('@vendor/tomaivanovtomov/yii2-revolution/views/slide/index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'hidden' => $hidden
        ]);
    }
```

This way it properly renders the view but error `Undefined variable: hidden` occures. Any sugestions why is that ? Thank you!
**EDIT**
Index file:

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ListView;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use backend\components\BackendPrefix;

\kartik\file\FileInputAsset::register($this);

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\SlideSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Slides');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addSlideModel('<?= BackendPrefix::PREFIX ?>')"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Add slide') ?></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php

        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'options' => [
                'multipart/form-data'
            ],
            'action' =>  [
                'slide/create'
            ],
            'id' => 'slides'
        ]);

        //Hidden model to enable UploadFile class
        echo $form->field($hidden, 'image[]')->fileInput(['class' => 'display-n'])->label(false);

        echo ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'layout' => "{items}",
            'itemView' => function( $model, $key, $index, $widget ){
                return $this->render("_slideImage", [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'index' => $index
                ]);
            },
        ]);

    ?>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group mt20">
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
         ActiveForm::end();
    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Youe question is not clear  "This way it properly renders the view but error Undefined variable: hidden occures"  . what mean?  .. eventually show also you index view code  .

Comment: It means that it reaches the view file `index` but no parameters are passed to it. Index file is added. See above.